# Integrate actual robot into moveit(other way than ros_control?)

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-control, arm-controller

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello sir,
as a beginner, i just completed tutorials and found out the solution pretty near to it. but however, before proceeding, i think there must be another simpler way to do it....and here is my problem- i have written topics which when called without arguments gives joint positions, and if called with arguments, executes requested joint positions(though it should be service(to confirm for correct execution), i havent written so, thinking i might require to access them in multiple ways)(through these topics, i can only control joint position and speed(neither effort nor other parameter))
now how can i integrate into moveit? i mean, should i have to write ros_control for it or simply i have to publish(through a node-topics) to topics(like joint states), somewhere in moveit infrastructure?
thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217971/integrate-actual-robot-into-moveit(other-way-than-ros_control?)/) by [baiju](https://answers.ros.org/users/22012/baiju/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2015-09-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you have a `sensor_msgs:/JointState` publisher and a `control_msgs/FollowJointTrajectory` action server, you should be able to integrate with MoveIt!. Any solution *properly* exposing these interfaces should work.

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2015-09-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [baiju](https://answers.ros.org/users/22012/baiju/) on 2015-09-28**:
thank you.thank you very much....actually, thats what i was exactly searching for..thanks.

**Comment by [t27](https://answers.ros.org/users/27290/t27/) on 2017-01-03**:
Hey @adolfo-rodriguez-t, my hardware has an inbuilt position control algo(PID), so i dont actually need the PID control etc from ros_control. If i just need moveit's IK and collision detection, is it ok if I implement these actions and publisher, will I lose anything if I dont implement ros_control?

**Comment by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) on 2017-01-05**:
It is perfectly acceptable to use MoveIt without ros_control.
As Adolfo wrote above: as long as you provide the JointState and a FollowJointTrajectory action server, everything is fine.